# Changing php content after copy files

Tags: php

I have the code bellow where I'm creating a new folder and copying some files from another folder, and it's working fine.
Now I need to go on each php file inside new folder and change the word "empty" by some word passed through $_POST["variable"]. 
Maybe by str_replace but I'm stuck in the logic.
Thanks in advance!

```
    if (!file_exists("/home//public_html/new_conf_folder/")) 
{
      mkdir("/home//public_html/new_conf_folder/", 0755, true);

      $source = "/home/public_html/conf_folder/";

      $destination = "/home/public_html/new_conf_folder";

      $directory = opendir($source);

      while(($file = readdir($directory)) != false) 
      { 

        copy($source.'/' .$file, $destination.'/'.$file);

      } 
    }
```

Comment: I presume you have dealt with the risk of code injection here.

Comment: Hi @symcbean, what kind of risk please? I've read somethings about symfony. Is it better? Thx

Comment: Don't try using frameworks until you've learnt the base language/technology. If the user has *any* control over the destination filename, they can inject any code they like into the file which will then execute on your server.

Comment: Oh yes! I have that in mind. User can't know It's all behind the scenes. I just need that to create folder for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code its working for me:**

```
// file_process.php
$destination="./"; // Current Directory
if (file_exists($destination)) 
{  
      $directory = opendir($destination);
      while(($file = readdir($directory)) != false) 
      { 
        //echo $file."<br/>";
        $contents=file_get_contents($file);
        $contents=str_replace("\"empty\"",$_POST['variable'],$contents);
        //$contents=str_replace("\"empty\"",$_POST['variable'],$contents); // use this if the word with qouts
        //echo $contents;
        $bytes_written=file_put_contents($file,$contents);
        if($bytes_written>0)echo "File [$file] has been successfully processed.";
        else echo "Process Failed.";
      } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user2448808, but there's something wrong. It's not writing the files.I've edited your code and it's working and showing the changed strings, but when I check the directory, nothing has changed. The error log gave me that msg file_put_contents(.): failed to open stream: Is a directory

Comment: i think its a permission issue , please try put 755 permission in the destination folder and change group for your user.

Comment: The permissions and user are ok.

Comment: That's weird. When I use $destination="./"; And put file_process.php inside the current folder it works. But when I use from outside even the code in file_process.php ( $contents = str_replace(":empty:",$word,$contents);
) is changing.

Comment: thanks @user2448808, I've changed the path on file_get_content and file_put_content and it's working now. I appreciate!